# dirty mind ,dirty action and dirty people

Tags: single-word-requests

What word to use to mean dirty mind ,dirty action and dirty people?

Something long as it don't get close to me, or don't happen to me or don't do something to me, I will be fine.

Example: No matter how much evilness in society, long as I stay secured, I will be fine.

Any better word other than evilness, unlucky?  I want a good word for this.

Thank you

Comment: ...a little like racism?

Comment: @Cascabel   I think it's not, because I embrace all races and any race don't mean bad or good to me.           Something like "Evilism"?

Comment: You need to provide more context, some research, and the sample sentence as required by the SWR tag.

Comment: 'Untowardness' might fit. Or 'wrongfulness'.

Comment: Whoa...I think this is going beyond our expertise. You mean that as long as you can maintain your distance from strangers you feel secure?

Comment: @Cascabel I mean maintain the distance from strangers,the dangerous mechine,animals, even bad contract that tries to trick for my money. I love the energy on this board, everyone solves everyone's problem !:)

Comment: @Strawberryttt Are you a native speaker?  I think you might do well on our sister site. Http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**undesirable**: "a person considered to be objectionable in some way" (Oxford).

This is a very derogatory term.

Comment: Like un-think-able,  I say the undesirable as noun? Undesire as noun don't conclude the meaning you say

Comment: No, the word undesirable is also noun by itself. For example a group of people can be called "undesirables."

Comment: What type of grammar is this? Could you give me a link or a grammar name for me to search on this site?  This grammar is interesting and I never learn it.  Thanks

Comment: "But when applied to the mentally ill and other undesirables, the euthanasia movement became tied to the eugenics movement." — Grazie Pozo Christie, National Review, "When Does the Right to Die Become the Duty to Die?," 13 Feb. 2018

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undesirable#examples Click "see more" and see the noun usages.

Comment: Interesting! I learn something new! Mind changing to me.  "Undesirables" means people,   "The undersirables" means the matters,object? something like a content word?   Gimme your grammar!

Comment: It doesn't have to refer to people, it's like "bad." "Take the good, leave the bad" can refer to good and bad things, people, food, etc. In this case "good" and "bad" are used as nouns, same with "undesirable" or "undesirables."

Answer (score 0):

The title and first sentence could be about people who are

> [**grubby**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/grubby)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1.1** Involving dishonest or disreputable activity; sordid.
>   *the grubby business of selling arms*

with the result of [**grubbiness**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/grubbiness) in society. Your sentence could be

> No matter how much grubbiness in society, as long as I stay secured, I will be fine.

<sub>From Lexico</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[**No-goodnik**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-goodnik) or [**low-life**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lowlife) both mean a person of low moral character. Both fit your request equally well.

Comment: Does these also the bad contract trying to trick for my money? What I mean is What's bad to the common standard we all have,but in term of violence, law that against me

Comment: @Strawberryttt these are words for bad people who do bad things.  You can use them to describe people who violate the law, cheat people, and hurt people.

Comment: @Cascabel agreed. I suggested ELL above.